# concatenating linux program outputs, and returning only those which repeat

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have multiple programs which each produce lines of output. How do I concatenate those outputs, and then only return one copy of each line which repeated at least once? In other words, I want to return the [set intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of all response lines.

for example:

```
$ progA
9
13
14
15
$ progA --someFlag
13
14
15
100
$ progB
14
15
-42
$ magicFunction 'progA' 'progA --someFlag' 'progB'
14
15
```

This doesn't have to be a function per se. I just wanted a unix command-line way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions above don't really compute the set intersection of all 3 outputs. `uniq -d` will also output lines which are output only by 2 of the 3 programs.
Here's my take on it:

`progA | sort > f1; progA --someFlag | sort > f2; progB | sort > f3; comm -1 -2 f1 f2 | comm -1 -2 f3 -; rm f[123]`

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
( progA; progA --someFlag; progB ) | sort | uniq -d
```

The `-d` option for `uniq` forces it to output only lines with more than one copy.

Here's a variant of the one-liner above that does not use a subshell:

```
{ progA; progA --someFlag; progB; } | sort | uniq -d
```

This works at least in `bash`. Note the required terminating semicolon (`;`) after the last command in the curly braces.

Comment: Bingo!! thanks. I'm so glad I just asked SO instead of trying to figure that out on my own :)